# How to show Vertical Progress Bar in react-transition-group with animation

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group, react-motion, react-spring

[Here](http://www.gerardolarios.com/plugins-and-tools/jqmeter/#demo) is a jQuery example for a progress bar animation. and I want this feature in Reactjs without jQuery. How to implement this feature.

[image]

Comment: Implement the class component with a state and timer which will be increasing the state's property every time you want a progress bar to move. You can find simple example of timer here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are still interested in this question. I just tinker with react-spring and I really love it. The best animation library in React IMHO.

You can create a neat component with the Spring component. It will always animate to the to property of the Spring component. First time from the from value of the from property.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import { Spring } from "react-spring";

const VerticalProgress = ({ progress }) => {
  return (
    <Spring from={{ percent: 0 }} to={{ percent: progress }}>
      {({ percent }) => (
        <div className="progress vertical">
          <div style={{ height: `${percent}%` }} className="progress-bar">
            <span className="sr-only">{`${progress}%`}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Spring>
  );
};

export default VerticalProgress;
```

Here is the complete  code: https://codesandbox.io/s/mqo1r9wo4j

Comment: How can I use tooltip also in this progress bar, If my progress bar is on 50% and I move mouse there then hover tooltip should show like this google chart http://lnnk.in/jCg

Comment: I'm not a tooltip expert. Our component library I use at work is proprietary. But I think you can use any kind of tooltip. For example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 1):

[Horizontal Example](https://codepen.io/felipe-segall-corr-a/pen/YJVxZJ)

Here is how to do it.

make 2 divs(container, progressing one)
you can change the height of progressing div based on state change.

```
const styled = styled.default;

const Bar = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1rem auto;
`

const Fill = styled.div`
  background: #0095da;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in;
  height: ${(props) => `${props.percentual}%`};
`

const ProgressBar = ({ percentage }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Bar>
        <Fill percentage={percentage} />
      </Bar>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProgressBar percentage={you state for progress percentage} />, document.getElementById('bar'));
```

you don't even need react for that tho.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_label_js